# Multidimensional array? Switching colors (in array) on items based on value in the same array

Tags: php, javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a solution to switch the colors of items looped out in a `foreach` loop.
All items should have a different color based on the value to the color.

Blue should be given 2 times while yellow should be given 5 times -in a sequence.

```
$colors = array
  (
  array("blue", 2),
  array("yellow", 5),
  array("green",4)
  );

foreach($colors as $color){
    foreach($color as $item){
        $colorClass = $item;
        echo $colorClass;
        //outputs blue8yellow12green16

    }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
blue
blue
yellow
yellow
yellow
yellow
yellow
green
green
green
green
```

Is there a way to do this?
I'm open to solve this in either php or javascript/jquery

Comment: Look into a [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution could be like this:

```
$colors = array
  (
  array("blue", 2),
  array("yellow", 5),
  array("green",4)
  );

foreach($colors as $color){

    $colorClass = $item[0];
    $colorCount = $item[1];
    for($i=0; $i<$colorCount; $i++) {
      echo $colorClass;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is brilliant! 

Though appearently not working completely with the situation, I didnt take into account that this must run inside a foreach-loop of comments in wordpress. Somehow it seems to be printing all the comments in an endless loop now. Though, thankfully, it does it with the correct interval.

I havent managed to change the outside loop of comments to a while-version, not sure that would be the correct way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some javascript :

```
var colors = [["blue",2],["yellow",5],["green",4]];
var colorClass = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    for (var g = 0; g < colors[i][1]; g++) {
        colorClass.push(colors[i][0]);
    }
}
output -> ["blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green", "green"]
```

The good in this code is that you can add more colors without changing the algorithm

Comment: How would the .push() work in php? array_push($colorClass[$i][0]); is not working..

Comment: you can use $colorClass[count($colorClass)] = $i; this will add the element to the last position of the array

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the sequence of strings, use `string_repeat`:

```
foreach($colors as $color){
    echo str_repeat($color[0] . "\n", $color[1]);
}
```

If you want to do stuff with the color name, you can stick with a `for` loop:

```
foreach($colors as $color){

    for($i = 0; $i<$color[1]; $i++){

        // do stuff with $color[0] here
        // this loop will go on for $color[1] times

    }

}
```